# Mistakenly deleted files recursively from '/' on my still running server

Tags: server, data-recovery, rm

I mistakenly deleted the bin folder, now most of the bin cmds do not exist. The server  still works just fine but I know when I restart it, I will not like it. How can I fix this without losing system configurations and data.

*from comment:*

I was trying to reinstall roundcube on the server and deleting the previous conf file. I had switched into the directory and instead of entering `rm -R .` I typed `rm -R /*` Realizing this I quickly cancelled the rm and unfortunately the `/bin` was already gone.

Comment: What bin folder exactly? `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, or even `/sbin`? or `/home/username/bin`? Really, be more specific. And you've tagged your question `12.04`, but your question says Ubuntu 11.10 (end-of-life, off-topic). And *how exactly* did you remove this folder? Please **edit** your question to provide more details.

Comment: Sorry about the version gertvdijk, I was trying to reinstall roundcube on the server and deleting the previous conf file. I had switched into the directory and instead of entering rm -R . I typed rm -R /* Realizing this I quickly cancelled the rm and unfortunately the /bin was already gone

Comment: Please post the command you used to `switch` into the directory, so that we can know which directory you operated from.

Comment: /var/www/webmail

Comment: Headshot! You are lucky that you did not type `rm -Rf /*`. May be filesystem journal would be helpful in this case...

Comment: @Danatela, Can you please explain how the filesystem journal can be used?

Comment: @Danatela, how would the filesystem journal help me fix this?

Comment: @saji89, sorry guys, I made guess and it was a mistake. I thought journal keeps track about changes that **were made**, but it turned out quite the contrary :(.

Answer (score 2):

By running the command `rm -R /*` you told it to recursively delete all, starting from `/`. This is likely very much more than just `/bin`.

**Your server now is in a highly unstable state and needs restore from backup.**

Only in case you have no backups, and your system is on an ext3 or ext4 partition, and you can still run it (which is not very likely I am afraid), you may try to recover files using [extundelete](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/extundelete) but you may not be able to recover all files, at least not to an extent to have a reliably stable system back.

Comment: I cannot install any packages any more. Whenever I run apt-get install <package_name> I get all the way through up to the point it says: "After this operation, 172 KB of additional disk space will be used." And then an error message "E: Sub-process /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true returned an error code (100) E: Failure running script /usr/sbin/dpkg-preconfigure --apt || true

Comment: Yeah, after deleting from `/` this is the expected behaviour. In case you need to recover files you may have to do this from booting a live system on the server (or carry the drive to another machine whichever is easier for you).